# Switch statement in JavaScript is not able to run my code Properly

Tags: javascript

```js
var aged = 14;

switch (aged) {
  case aged <= 13:
    document.write("Child");
    break;
  case aged >= 14 && aged <= 18:
    document.write("Teen");
    break;
  case aged >= 19 && aged <= 59:
    document.write("Adult");
    break;
  default:
    document.write("Boomer");
}
```

it just keeps outputting BOOMER!!
I honestly don't know what to do
I got the syntax right but I'm still confused

Comment: `switch(true) {...` is what you'd need to get your code to work the way it is. This is because all the `case` branches yield a boolean value.

Comment: [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#Description) is for exact values. All `aged <= 13`, `aged >= 14 && aged <= 18` and `aged >= 19 && aged <= 59` will evaluate to either `true` or `false`, `aged` which equals `14` is neither `true` nor `false`, hence the behavior

Comment: Keeping in mind that the cases could be simplified.  It's only going to go to the second case if it doesn't match the first cause, due to the `break;`  And for it to go to the second case, the first case had to be false so you know the age is at least 14

Comment: If your judgment condition is ``aged``, then the comparison object of ``case`` is number rather than Boolean, so you need to change the judgment condition

Answer (score 3):

Because each of your case branches provide a `boolean` value, you need to match against a boolean.

Your logic is such that you want to enter a branch upon a `true` evaluation, so use `true` in the head of the `switch`.

```js
var aged = 14;

switch (true){
    case aged <= 13:
        document.write("Child");
        break;
    case aged >= 14 && aged <= 18:
        document.write( "Teen" );
        break;
    case aged >= 19 && aged <= 59:
        document.write("Adult");
        break;
    default:
        document.write("Boomer");
}
```

---

I think `if/else` would maybe be preferable here.

```js
var aged = 14;

if (aged <= 13) {
        document.write("Child");
} else if (aged >= 14 && aged <= 18) {
        document.write( "Teen" );
} else if (aged >= 19 && aged <= 59) {
        document.write("Adult");
} else {
        document.write("Boomer");
}
```

---

You could also use the conditional operator, but I'd use it to provide a value instead of control the flow of the program.

```js
var aged = 14;

var result = aged <= 13               ? "Child" :
             aged >= 14 && aged <= 18 ? "Teen"  :
             aged >= 19 && aged <= 59 ? "Adult" :
                                        "Boomer";
document.write(result);
```

---

And your conditions are a little redundant. You can simplify like this:

```js
var aged = 14;

var result = aged <= 13 ? "Child" :
             aged <= 18 ? "Teen"  :
             aged <= 59 ? "Adult" :
                          "Boomer";
document.write(result);
```

Comment: Hmmm, you're fortunate I'm currently too lazy to downvote the nested ternaries.

Comment: @Taplar: Why would you do that? When they can be nested cleanly, they're no less readable that `if/else`. The argument against that is when they lead to unreadable code. That isn't the case here.

Comment: Nested ternaries are often related to reduced code readability, which is always more favorable to negligible performance gains.

Comment: @Taplar: Yes, they often are. That doesn't mean we throw them out when they're not unreadable. I'd say that the code is actually clearer than the `switch` or `if` examples. There's no performance gain either way. It all gets reduced to the same logic on compilation.